# What is the full Optical Density representation range of shades of gray in a Dicom CT image?

Tags: dicom

For normal images the range of shades of gray is from 0 to 256, what is it for Dicom CT monochrome images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Techically, I agree with Amit Joshi. But especially for CT images you will usually find a grayscale range expressed in Hounsfield Units. These range from -1000 to +4000. By applying a linear transformation of the pixel data as specified by the attributes Rescale Intercept (0028,1052) and Rescale Slope (0028,1053), pixel data as described by Amit Joshi's anwer are mapped to that range.

To this range, the windowing (VOI LUT) funtion is applied.

[EDIT]
A little explanation on Hounsfield units (HU)...

HU are valid for CT images only. A range of HU corresponds to a particular type of tissue or depicted structures, e.g.

```
-1000 -> air
0 -> fat
10-40 -> kidney
```

and so on.

So in CT images, pixel values found in the file are usually mapped to HU using Rescale Slope and -Intercept. Whether or not the this is the case is indicated by the attribute Rescale Type (0028,1054). HUs are not only used for measuring grayvalues and deducing tissue type from the median value but also for windowing. In CT, you refer to "bone window", "tissue window" etc.

So the relevant part of the DICOM Grayscale Standard Display Function (GSDF, see PS3.14) is:

- interpret the pixel values according to their type description (signed/unsigned, bpp)
- map the pixel values to HU using Rescale Slope and -Intercept
- apply windowing to HU, i.e. map the range of the HU defined by the window to the display range (usually 256 grayscales)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about Optical Density Representation.

Shades of gray can be calculated by `2^Bits Stored`.

For CT images, Bits Stored may be 10 to 16 depending on manufacturer and other factors.
Considering value 16, shades are 65536.

For unsigned image: -
Start value: 0
End value: 65536

For signed image: -
Start value: -32768
End value: 32768

CT images are generally signed. In signed images, 0 is center and range is split half negative values and half positive values.

Comment: Do I have to specify a range for every image, because I have some with 14 bits and others with 17 bits or there is a general range that I'm going to use like 256 gray levels for usual images.

Comment: You should read Bits Stored value from DICOM Tag for each image. Generally, all images in single series have same value; but do not rely on this.